# Is there a way to import in es6 a css file that only applies to one specific element and isnt global?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6

In React I have a Component and I want to import a css stylesheet

```
import styles from 'css-stylesheet.css'
```

or

```
import 'css-stylesheet.css'
```

in './MyComponent.jsx'

However I only want this css to apply to THIS COMPONENT ONLY!  I dont want it to be global as it is now.  I am using webpack. Is there a way to import css locally and only apply it to the file I imported it from?  Seems like there should be a way but I cant even find a question about it.

Here is my webpack css loader code

```
module: {
   rules: [{test: /(\.css)$/, loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']}]
}
```

Comment: are you married to using css files? there are lots of solutions for this like styled-components or glamor

Comment: I dont want to get too exotic as this is a project at my job being worked on by multiple people. Simpler = better.

Comment: fair enough. I would still look at styled-components. https://www.styled-components.com/ it uses normal css syntax and is hardly exotic

Answer (score 1):

You are using css-loader, it supports [css-modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules), to enable it you should pass an option

```
{
  loader: "css-loader",
  options: {
    modules: true
  }
}
```

That will return you an object whenever you're importing css, and that object will contain a map between your css selectors to uglified selector, in that way, the styles are unique to the component.

You can define the pattern of the uglified selector, by adding additional field to the options.
`localIdentName:[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]`

Comment: Thank you!! If i have other imported css how do I make those global?

Comment: There is a documentation for that, but as a short answer, there is a :global declaration that you will need to wrap your global css with.

Comment: Thats the thing...I cant wrap that css because its 3rd party and I dont want to monkey around with it.  Is there a good writeup or article of where to look at this..the documentation is scarce on how I configure css to be global and local.  Thanks for the help Felix, it sent me on the right path

Comment: On closer inspection this is not going to work for me. I need to import some css globally and import css locally without knowing the names of the classes specifically

Comment: You can try to @import your 3rd party css into some css, and wrap it with :global declaration.